# How to send a compiled file to sama5d27 board and execute it?

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, yocto

I am using yocto project.

I have a sama5d27 som1 ek1 board. I made it bootable from SD card. Now I want to cross compile a `Helloworld.c` file and execute it on sama5 board.

The problem is: how send the .bin compiled file from my host machine to sama5 board and execute it ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use any network transfer protocol (scp, ftp, ..) if it is installed in your sdcard image. Otherwise, you can also put it offline directly to sdcard mounted on build machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also create a nfs server on your host PC (really easy for example on Ubuntu) and install nfs client in your Yocto image which is already installed in the standard images from the meta-atmel (atmel-demo-image, etc).

Once running, you can mount the nfs volume inside your target with the following command:

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs <host ip address>:<host mounting point> /mnt
```

It creates a bridge between your target and your PC which is really useful for dev.
It's then really easy to work, compile, recompile on the host and to have the result directly inside the target as long as the result of the compilation is directly inside the exported directory of your host.

P.S.: You need to allow your target (IP range is possible) in the file /etc/exports of your host system as probably explained in the nfs server setup of your host distro.

Edit: Concerning the way how to execute the binary, you need first of all to make it executable if not already.

```
$ chmod +x <the binary>
```

You can know if the file is executable using the command ls with -la args:

```
$ ls -la
total 13776
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user     4096 May 11 16:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user     4096 May 11 16:34 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 14103552 May 11 16:35 binary.bin <- not executable
$ chmod +x binary.bin
$ ls -la
total 13776
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user     4096 May 11 16:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user     4096 May 11 16:34 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 14103552 May 11 16:35 binary.bin <- executable
```

Then run the binary:

```
$ ./binary.bin
hello world
```

Comment: Thanks for your replie, but you mentioned that nfs client is already installed in my yocto image , how can i verify it ? and so i don't have to modify anything in the image configurations and rebuild it ?

Comment: Following the recipe atmel-demo-image recipe, it includes packagegroup-core-full-cmdline which includes itself the package nfs-utils which should include the nfs client command (not sure). I can't guarantee it but I worked a lot with this hardware and don't remember to have needed to add nfs client to work with. The most simple is still to configure a server and to test it directly (less that 15 minutes needed if network if configured well for target and host)

Comment: OK I will follow the steps mentioned in your answer and i hope that will work with me. Thanks

Comment: Hello, while i am assigning server access to client ( sama5 board ) through NFS export file I need to allow my target ( with IP adress) in the file /etc/exports of my host system but i don't know how to get my sama5 IP adress , do you have any idea please ?

Comment: You can use the command **ifconfig** to display all your interfaces, you should then see the loopback (lo) and normally the ethernet one (eth0 or eth1) with the IP address you need. Your board should have received an address through DHCP (if I remember well about the default meta-atmel). You can also define a static IP address by editing the file **/etc/network/interfaces**, may be create another topic for that since it outside the scope of your initial question.